# Convert Existing Stored Procedure having multiple update statements on Mosaic

Tags: mosaic-decisions

I have a requirement to convert an existing **Stored procedure** having Multiple update statements.
Ex:

---

Current query in Stored procedure is -

---

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Load_Catalog]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
truncate table dbo..Dummy2

```
update A set Market = b.code_cmmt
From        dbo..Dummy2  A 
inner join  dbo..Dummy3 b on a.cm__chr03  = b.code_value and b.code_fldname = 'xar1'
```

How can this functionality be achieved on Mosaic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this functionality on **Mosaic Decisions**, follow the steps listed below:

1. Drag in a **Reader Node** and configure it with the information about the source data.

[image: reader node configuration]

2. Drag in the **Custom SQL Process Node**. Here, provide the `UPDATE` SQL queries that are equivalent to the logic mentioned in the **Stored Procedure**.

[image: custom sql node configuration]

3. Attach a **Writer Node** and configure it to update the existing table.

[image]

After execution of the flow, you should have the desired result.